# scss - an elegant way to loop through variables

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for an elegant way to make a scss file more maintainable. I have the following code, I have been looking at scss maps and @each ect, but I cant figure out an elegant scss way to write this - at the moment. I am going to put the colors into variables - its more the looping/map side of things I am looking for help with.

Any help appreciated.

This is my code at the moment.

```
        .grid-box--resource {
    &.--variant-blue {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 1);
        color: #fff;

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #E8F1FB;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 1);
        }
    }

    &.--variant-purple {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(167, 24, 241, 1);
        color: #fff;

        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(167, 24, 241, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #F4F2FF;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(167, 24, 241, 1);
        }
    }

    &.--variant-lightblue {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 1);
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #E8F1FB;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(46, 111, 255, 1);
        }

    }

    &.--variant-violet {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(154, 36, 243, 1);
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(154, 36, 243, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #F8F0FF;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(154, 36, 243, 1);
        }   
    }

    &.--variant-teal {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(4, 167, 175, 1);
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(4, 167, 175, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #E2F2F9;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(4, 167, 175, 1);
        }  

    }

    &.--variant-mint {
        .btn {
        background-color: rgba(17, 187, 148, 1);
        color: #fff;
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(17, 187, 148, 0.8);
        }
        }

        .bg-color {
            background-color: #EBF5F4;
        }

        .resource-card__icon i {
            color: rgba(17, 187, 148, 1);
        } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. As you said, you can put your variable in a map and loop through it, not sure about an "elegant" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$variants: (
    blue: (
        main: #2E6FFF,
        light: #E8F1FB
    ),
    purple: (
        main: #a718f1,
        light: #F4F2FF
    ),
    ...
);

.grid-box--resource {
    @each $variant, $colors in $variants {
        $main: map-get($colors, main);
        $light: map-get($colors, light);
        
        &.--variant-#{$variant} {
            .btn {
                background-color: $main;
                color: #fff;
        
                &:hover {
                    background-color: rgba($main, 0.8);
                }
            }
        
            .bg-color {
                background-color: $light;
            }
    
            .resource-card__icon i {
                color: $main;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use HEX color codes in `rgba()` directly.